# ImportError: No module named django_filters

Tags: django, django-filter

I am using Django 1.7.1 and I pip installed django-filters to my virtual env at `/.virtualenvs/auction2/lib/python2.7/site-packages$`

It said it was installed successfully.

So I placed django-filters in installed apps like so:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django_filters',
    'donations',
)
```

I ran `python manage.py runserver` and got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/Dani/.virtualenvs/auction2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/Dani/.virtualenvs/auction2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/Dani/.virtualenvs/auction2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/Dani/.virtualenvs/auction2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/Users/Dani/.virtualenvs/auction2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 87, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named django_filters
```

It said it installed, but why can't it import it?  I have another package, crispy-forms, installed and working.  I looked at my site packages on the virtual environment and I saw:

```
crispy_forms
django
django_braces-1.4.0.dist-info
django_crispy_forms-1.4.0-py2.7.egg-info
django_filters-0.1.0-py2.7.egg-info
easy_install.py
easy_install.pyc
filters
pip
```

Seeing that it goes in as 'filters' instead of what the documentation says to import it as (django_filters), I thought I'd try changing it to just 'filters' in installed_apps.

I stoped and started the runserver, no problem, so I began building my filter in `filter.py`:

```
import django_filters
from donations.models import Donor, Item, Issue

class DonorFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Donor
        fields = {'type':['exact'],'donor':['icontains'],}

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(DonorFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.filters['type'].extra.update(
                {'empty_label': 'All Types'})
```

I stop and start the runserver, no problem.  Then I start adding a view and just the import statement at views.py:

```
from donations.filters import DonorFilter
```

gives me the same `ImportError: No module named django_filters.`  error.

I tried changing the import in my filters.py to filters rather than django_filters and the errors didn't change.  I changed everything back to  django_filters (in installed_apps and my filters.py) as the documentation says to do, I get the error `global name 'DonorFilter' is not defined` when I add the view.  Here is the view.py:

```
def donor_list(request):
    f = DonorFilter(request.GET, queryset=Donor.objects.all())
    return render_to_response('donations/donor_list', {'filter': f})
```

That means I need to import the function I created in filters.py?  So I add
`from donations.filters import DonorFilter` to the top of my view.
Then the error is `'module' object has no attribute 'FilterSet'`

I can see the FilterSet class in the filters.py file installed in my virtualenv

I noticed there is more development on django-filter, the https://github.com/alex/django-filter page goes up to v0.9.2, but pip installs 0.1.0.  Should I be installing it another way (other than pip)?

Comment: Ok, one step at a time. There are so many errors it is difficult to answer just One. First of all, if you put in your settings.py in `INSTALLED_APPS` the app 'filters' and in your .py you import `filters` instead of django_filter , what happens?

Comment: Thank you, I know I have a big mess!  If I put 'filters' in `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.py and `import filters' in my filters.py the errors are gone.  I can access my app but there is no filter on the page.  The submit button for the filter is there, but nothing else.

Comment: To anybody else stuck on this: make sure you're not trying to import `django-filter` (notice the dash rather than underscore).

Comment: If you install django with pip3, then you need to install all other django libs with pip3 as well

Answer (score 73, accepted):

My pip version was old, really old. 1.5.6  When I installed my virtual environment it just worked, so I didn't question.  Lesson learned!  Here is what I did in case it helps someone else...

In the virtual environment, I installed pip as described in the docs:
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing.html
`python get-pip.py`   This upgraded me to pip 6.1.1

```
pip install django-filter
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Reading requirements.txt showed I had

```
django-filter==0.9.2
django-filters==0.1.0
```

So I uninstalled the older version with `pip uninstall django-filters`

**notice the s on the older version but not on the new one**

Really basic stuff but it really tripped me up.  Thanks to anyone who took time to look into this!

Comment: Wow, the more you know. `pip freeze` will save a ton of time for me in the future until I move on to Docker.

Answer (score 13):

I also had the same issue. Even after installing `django-filters` I couldn't import it

> ImportError: No module named django_filters

The Django version I'm using is 1.8 and python version is 2.7.x

**Solution** is to install `djangorestframework-filters`

```
pip install djangorestframework-filters
```

The names are very confusing.

However `django-rest-framework-filters` is an extension to Django REST framework and Django filter that makes it easy to filter across relationships while `Django-filter` is a reusable Django application allowing users to declaratively add dynamic QuerySet filtering from URL parameters.

Answer (score 12):

I also encountered this issue installing django-filter==2.2.0

This was my Django version:

```
Django [required: >=1.11, installed: 2.2]
```

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    'django_filter',
]
```

This is the correct installation:

```
pipenv install django-filter
```

Comment: Just to highlight here, that's an underscore (_) in the INSTALLED_APPS list, and a dash (-) in the pip install command. Seemed to make a difference for me.

Answer (score 4):

I changed from `django_filter` to `django_filters` in installed apps and it was okay.

Comment: but i changed from **django_filters** to **django_filters** then it worked for me

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue using django 1.7, djangorestframework==3.2.0 and latest django-filter==0.13.0:

```
Using DjangoFilterBackend, but django-filter is not installed
cannot import name Expression
```

I finally fixed it by downgrading django-filter to 0.11.

Now pip freeze looks like this and its working:

```
Django==1.7
django-filter==0.11.0
djangorestframework==3.2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

We install it using: `pip install django-filter` or in case you are using a virtual environment like pipenv, use `pipenv install django-filter .`

> the above install, adds the latest version of django-filter. Add "==version" to specify the version ( say 0.11.0) you need

In the settings.py under app, ensure it's `'django_filters',`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    'django_filters',
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried all of the above answers and none of them worked for me. I later learnt that the pip script is not installing modules for the interpreter that the python command is using.

SOLUTION:

```
python -m pip install django-filter
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure its `django_filters` and not `django-filters` in settings.py. Also keep in find it's not `django-filter`, it's `django-filters`.
But to install it:

```
pip install django-filter
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed `django_filters` in the settings `INSTALLED_APPS`. this is worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced the same problem but i realized its because i had installed django-filter when am in the virtual environment.
I tried installing django-filter at the same directory without activating the virtual environment and it worked

I used

```
pip install django-filter
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]
In my case, the issue was Interpreter, After wasting a day finally resolved the issue. Always check you are selecting the right Interpreter. I was getting this error before fixing the issue:
"django_filters" is not accessedPylance
Import "django_filters" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports
Though I see requirment.txt showing django_filters 23.1