# No module named django_filters

Tags: python, django, filter, django-filter, django-filters

I'm new to python and perhaps this questions is obvious to some of you but I searched everywhere for an answer and I can't seem to find it.

I am trying to install "django-filter into my website, and i was able to successfully do so. However, when I add it to my "installed apps", it gives me the following error: "import error: no module named django_filters"

based on my research, I figured it must be a compatibility problem, so I downgraded by django to 1.8.4, and downgraded my filter to 0.11.0.

after doing pip freeze > requirements.txt, everything seems to show up fine in requirements.txt. I am using python 2.7.

I know there was a similar question, like the one below: 
[ImportError: No module named django_filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29929178/importerror-no-module-named-django-filters)

But none of the solutions for this thread worked.

Any ideas what the issue may be? Thanks so much in advance.

```
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named django_filters
(bartering) localhost:src ayaspencer$ pip freeze
Django==1.8.4
django-crispy-forms==1.6.0
django-filter==0.11.0
django-localflavor==1.2
django-registration==2.0.4
django-registration-redux==1.4
httplib2==0.9.2
oauth2client==2.0.2
Pillow==3.2.0
pyasn1==0.1.9
pyasn1-modules==0.0.8
requests==2.9.1
rsa==3.4.2
six==1.10.0
South==1.0.2
stripe==1.32.1
```

Here is my INSTALLED_APPS

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    #django app
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    #third party apps
    'crispy_forms',
    'localflavor',
    'registration',
    'django_filters',
```

Comment: Please share your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

Comment: Hi rnevius. just edited my post. thanks!!

Comment: I don't know much about Django, and you have already looked at the other thread, but - in the error message of your question I see `django-filter==0.11.0`, while in your `INSTALLED_APPS` files is `django-filters` (the first one is singular, the second one plural). What happens if you write `django-filter` (without the "s" at the end) in your apps file instead?

Comment: unfortunately that wont work either. i followed the directions for installation here: https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

Comment: I see something weird going on. You have activated the virtual env, but the pip freeze gives you the output of the globally installed pip packages. May be the virtual env is not installed properly?

Comment: pardon me, but is there a reason to add django_filters to your installed apps? this is library not the app module... remove it from list and use it in the code via normal import

Answer (score 3):

The issue is almost certainly that you are running the server in a different python environment from the one in which you ran `pip freeze`.

Do the following to debug the default environment on the command line:

```
pip --version
python --version
python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
```

Then add the following code to your `settings.py` and re-run your server to get similar information about the environment you're running in:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
print(sys.path)
```

What you'll find is that the two `sys.path`s are different, and you'll need to fix something up to make sure they're the same. Also if the versions are different then you've got an even worse environment issue!

As a general hint, if you're using python at all seriously you need to learn how to use [virtual environments](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) (it's not hard), and get in the habit of using them all the time!

Comment: thanks all! Yes, the issue was indeed in the way that i improperly installed my pip package. I restarted my python project and installed pip package properly and created a virtual environment, and now it works. thanks!

Comment: Glad you got it working! If my answer was correct then feel free to mark it as such :-)